# data error in BMA package's bic.glm but not glm

Tags: r, glm

I am estimating a poisson model from a set of interaction coefficients, and the BMA package's bic.glm helps navigate the model space. I've been using it for years, but when I updated R from 2.10.x to 2.14.2 last night, it stopped working. Here's the error: first, a call that works:

```
> glm(formula(Y~.), data=XY5, family=poisson)

Call:  glm(formula = formula(Y ~ .), family = poisson, data = XY5)

Coefficients:
<results, etc>
```

Now bic.glm failing:

```
> bic.glm(formula(Y~.), data=XY5, glm.family=poisson, model=TRUE)
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  '.' in formula and no 'data' argument
```

Again, this exact code worked in the earlier version of R with five systems. When I run bic.glm with 4 interacting systems instead of 5 (i.e., drop x5 and collapse the interactions), bic.glm runs fine. I'll include the five system data below. Thanks in advance.

```
> XY5
   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x12 x13 x14 x15 x23 x24 x25 x34 x35 x45 x123 x124 x125 x134 x135 x145
2   0  0  0  0  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0
3   0  0  0  1  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0
4   0  0  0  1  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1    0    0    0    0    0    0
5   0  0  1  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0
6   0  0  1  0  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0    0    0    0    0    0    0
7   0  0  1  1  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0
8   0  0  1  1  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1    0    0    0    0    0    0
9   0  1  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0
10  0  1  0  0  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0
11  0  1  0  1  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0
12  0  1  0  1  1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1    0    0    0    0    0    0
13  0  1  1  0  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0
14  0  1  1  0  1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0    0    0    0    0    0    0
15  0  1  1  1  0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0
16  0  1  1  1  1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1    0    0    0    0    0    0
17  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0
18  1  0  0  0  1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0
19  1  0  0  1  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0
20  1  0  0  1  1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1    0    0    0    0    0    1
21  1  0  1  0  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0
22  1  0  1  0  1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0    0    0    0    0    1    0
23  1  0  1  1  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0    0    0    0    1    0    0
24  1  0  1  1  1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1    0    0    0    1    1    1
25  1  1  0  0  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0
26  1  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0    0    0    1    0    0    0
27  1  1  0  1  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0    0    1    0    0    0    0
28  1  1  0  1  1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1    0    1    1    0    0    1
29  1  1  1  0  0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0    1    0    0    0    0    0
30  1  1  1  0  1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0    1    0    1    0    1    0
31  1  1  1  1  0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0    1    1    0    1    0    0
32  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1    1    1    1    1    1
   x234 x235 x245 x345 x1234 x1235 x1245 x1345 x2345    Y
2     0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0 1276
3     0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0  714
4     0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0  481
5     0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0  628
6     0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0  365
7     0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0  836
8     0    0    0    1     0     0     0     0     0 1343
9     0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0 1348
10    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0  161
11    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0  266
12    0    0    1    0     0     0     0     0     0  239
13    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0  144
14    0    1    0    0     0     0     0     0     0  135
15    1    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0  469
16    1    1    1    1     0     0     0     0     1 1356
17    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0  594
18    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0  431
19    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0   18
20    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0   83
21    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0   22
22    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0   16
23    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0   12
24    0    0    0    1     0     0     0     1     0   29
25    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0   16
26    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0    3
27    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0    2
28    0    0    1    0     0     0     1     0     0    3
29    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0    6
30    0    1    0    0     0     1     0     0     0    0
31    1    0    0    0     1     0     0     0     0   11
32    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1    9
```

Comment: after turning trace on and off, the error changes to "Error in as.environment(where) : invalid 'pos' argument." I don't feel closer, but it's always good to be able to affect the error, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering on behalf of the BMA package team, to whom I'm very grateful. Here's what they said:

> I think there may be some unanticipated degeneracy due to the discrete
>   nature of the data that is causing this problem to surface. I will
>   update the package accordingly, but you should be able to fix it by
>   adding the line indicated below to bic.glm.data.frame (and
>   bic.glm.matrix)

```
while (length(glm.out$coefficients) > maxCol) {
           any.dropped <- TRUE
           dropglm <- drop1(glm.out, test = "Chisq")
           dropped <- which.max(dropglm$"Pr(Chi)"[-1]) + 1
#
           if (length(dropped) == 0) break  #### add to prevent bug
#
           x.df <- x.df[, -(dropped - 1)]
           designx.levels <- designx.levels[-dropped]
           designx <- designx[-dropped]
```

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error message. Considering that this message was posted 9 years ago, and yet I am getting the error message about the backlog I would contribute a little on what I have found and solved.

It could be the sample size. Though BMA has declared itself as a package for data containing small sample size and many variables, there is a lower limit . An attempt to increase the sample size and perform a run would be ideal.

The next possible issue would be collinearity in one or more of the variables. The package has designed itself in such an intelligent way that it could pick up small signs of collinearity. A prime example would be variable Z was derived from parts of Variable A; given that Variable Z was generated by the analyst. Although it doesn't cause problems in glm (binomial or poisson or gamma), it does lead to convergence problems in bic.glm .  Analysts would have to omit the specific variable.

If the main issue was predominantly due to the latter, I doubt the BMA developers would have it fixed.