# Generating PR curves using boosting methods

Tags: r

I'm attempting to generate a set of precision/response curves in R using AdaBoost and gradient boosting (packages ada and gbm, respectively) by modifying the code in chapter 4 of Torgo's "Data Mining with R".  The sample code is here: http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~ltorgo/DataMiningWithR/code4.html.

Torgo does implement AdaBoost, but with a different package (as I said, I'm attempting to use package ada).  However, I've been unable to swap methods without returning one error or another.  If anyone has any insight, it would be appreciated.

Thanks

gh

EDIT:

Here's what I'm attempting:

The data is a set of sales data on which I'm trying to build several supervised learning models.  The response variable is "Insp" which has three values - unkn, ok, and fraud.  All unkn entries are removed from the dataset before moving forward.  It looks like this:

```
      ID  Prod Quant   Val Insp    Uprice
1         v1    p1   182  1665 unkn  9.148352
2         v2    p1  3072  8780 unkn  2.858073
3         v3    p1 20393 76990 unkn  3.775315
4         v4    p1   112  1100 unkn  9.821429
5         v3    p1  6164 20260 unkn  3.286827
6         v5    p2   104  1155 unkn 11.105769
7         v6    p2   350  5680 unkn 16.228571
411816 v5896 p4127   143  1835 unkn 12.832168
411817 v1796 p4127   102  1445 unkn 14.166667
411818 v2540 p4127   106  1275 unkn 12.028302
```

The code provides two working supervised learning examples, Naive Bayes and AdaBoostM1, implementing a hold-out routine to cross-validate.  The final output is a PR curve.  The code for these are as follows:

```
nb <- function(train,test) {
  require(e1071,quietly=T)
  sup <- which(train$Insp != 'unkn')
  data <- train[sup,c('ID','Prod','Uprice','Insp')]
  data$Insp <- factor(data$Insp,levels=c('ok','fraud'))
  model <- naiveBayes(Insp ~ .,data)
  preds <- predict(model,test[,c('ID','Prod','Uprice','Insp')],type='raw')
  return(list(rankOrder=order(preds[,'fraud'],decreasing=T),
             rankScore=preds[,'fraud'])
         )
}


ho.nb <- function(form, train, test, ...) {
  res <- nb(train,test)
  structure(evalOutlierRanking(test,res$rankOrder,...),
            itInfo=list(preds=res$rankScore,
                        trues=ifelse(test$Insp=='fraud',1,0)
                       )
           )
}


nb.res <- holdOut(learner('ho.nb',
                          pars=list(Threshold=0.1,
                                    statsProds=globalStats)),
                  dataset(Insp ~ .,sales),
                  hldSettings(3,0.3,1234,T),
                  itsInfo=TRUE)

summary(nb.res)
```

AdaBoostM1:

```
ab <- function(train,test) {
      require(RWeka,quietly=T)
      sup <- which(train$Insp != 'unkn')
      data <- train[sup,c('ID','Prod','Uprice','Insp')]
      data$Insp <- factor(data$Insp,levels=c('ok','fraud'))
      model <- AdaBoostM1(Insp ~ .,data,
                  control=Weka_control(I=100))
      preds <- predict(model,test[,c('ID','Prod','Uprice','Insp')],
               type='probability')
      return(list(rankOrder=order(preds[,'fraud'],decreasing=T),
               rankScore=preds[,'fraud'])
     )
}


  ho.ab <- function(form, train, test, ...) {
      res <- ab(train,test)
      structure(evalOutlierRanking(test,res$rankOrder,...),
            itInfo=list(preds=res$rankScore,
                        trues=ifelse(test$Insp=='fraud',1,0)
                   )
       )
}


ab.res <- holdOut(learner('ho.ab',
                      pars=list(Threshold=0.1,
                                statsProds=globalStats)),
              dataset(Insp ~ .,sales),
              hldSettings(3,0.3,1234,T),
              itsInfo=TRUE
              )


summary(ab.res)
```

What I'm attempting to do next is run this same type of methodology, except using gradient boosting (package gbm).  I make the corresponding changes (I would expect to be) necessary to the model command, as well as the predictor vector, but I'm getting an error that it isn't reading my dataset.

```
gb <- function(train, test) {
  require(gbm, quietly=T)
  sup <- which(train$Insp != 'unkn')
  data <- train[sup ,c('ID','Prod','Uprice','Insp')]
  data$Insp <- factor(data$Insp,levels=c('ok','fraud'))
  model <- gbm(Insp ~ .,data, n.trees = 100, shrinkage = 1)
  preds <- predict(model,test[,c('ID','Prod','Uprice','Insp')], n.trees = 100, type =             "response")
  return(list(rankOrder=order(preds[,'fraud'],decreasing=T),
          rankScore=preds[,'fraud'])
      )
    }


ho.gb <- function(form, train, test, ...) {
  res <- gb(train,test)
  structure(evalOutlierRanking(test,res$rankOrder,...),
            itInfo=list(preds=res$rankScore,
                        trues=ifelse(test$Insp=='fraud',1,0)
            )
      )
    }


gb.res <- holdOut(learner('ho.gb',
                      pars=list(Threshold=0.1,
                                statsProds=globalStats)),
              dataset(Insp~.,sales),
              hldSettings(3,0.3,1234,T),
              itsInfo=TRUE
)


summary(gb.res)
```

However R will return an error stating "Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument" so I guess it's not catching the data...

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi welcome to SO.  Generally, it is helpful if you can post more details, such as what specifically you have tried, what specific error you've encountered and what the intended output should be or look like.

Comment: Also, sample data, or at least what your data looks like, would be helpful.  You can use `reproduce(yourDataFrame)` to generate a copy+paste'able output.  available here: https://raw.github.com/rsaporta/pubR/gitbranch/reproduce.R

Comment: Hello! Sorry about that, I didn't want to clutter up my post with too much, but realized too little is also not helpful. I've edited above.

Answer (score 0):

You might be experiencing a parsing error related to the discrete nature of your factor variable`Insp`. Take a look at this question and see if the suggested fix also works for your gbm experiment:
[data error in BMA package's bic.glm but not glm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444117/data-error-in-bma-packages-bic-glm-but-not-glm)

Related: Could you clarify which versions of base R and packages you're using?